# Blogger feed by label or label (category or category)

Tags: blogger, feed

I found a lot of examples to get feed by multiple tags (labels, categories), but all of them works like [tag and tag]. I mean that one - blogname.com/feeds/posts/default/-/firstlabel/secondlabel...

But I need feed by formula - [tag or tag].

Example:
I have blog with tags: Flowers, Trees, Events, Animals
So I want to get posts only about Flowers and Trees.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Hahaha, I found answer in question of other person.                    
THat is what I want:[http://www.blogname.com/search/?q=label:Graphics|label:Identity|label:Brand]

Comment: May be it will helps somebody: http://narfisil.blogspot.ru/2013/07/blogger-multiple-label-query.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use the query syntax as below:

http://yourblogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/?q=label:Flowers|label:Trees